# svn merge perf problem on large branches

Tags: performance, svn, merge, branch

We have svn 1.6, a trunk with approx 30000 files (1 GB), and a "test" branch originally copied from trunk. When we are keeping our "test" branch in sync, the `svn merge ^/trunk` command takes a long time (30 min) although we are only changing a few files in a specific subdirectory.

**My question is:** Does anybody know a way to make the merge command faster?

**PS:** I don't understand why the command takes so much time (not going through the list of changed files but apparently going through the all repository). Does anybody knows ?

Comment: just a suggestion, try running `svn cleanup` before merge

Answer (score 0):

It is probably related to the number of sub-folders in your checkout. Each of them has an .svn folder which needs to be checked for local changes during the merge. This does not mean that having one huge folder with 30,000 files would be any faster, though...

Even in a smaller project, there is a noticeable difference in time it takes to do the same operation when running on a fast SSD drive vs. regular drive or a networked file system.